# Apache tomcat server 7.0.42 fails to start after running ant build script

Tags: ant

I am using apache ant 1.9.4. I have written build xml for starting apache tomcat server 7.0.42. But the server closes as soon it gets started. Also the build is showing successfull.

My build.xml is.,

```
<property name="build.dir" value="aar" />
<property name="deploy-location" value="D:\EIT SOFTWARES\apache-tomcat-7.0.42_aqar\webapps" />
<property name="catalina.home" value="D:\EIT SOFTWARES\apache-tomcat-7.0.42_aqar"/>
<property name="tomcat" value="${catalina.home}" />
<target name="start-tomcat">
    <echo message="Starting tomcat">
    </echo>
    <exec executable="${catalina.home}\bin\startup.bat"></exec>
    </echo>
</target>
```

What i am making wrong. Ant experts please help me.

Comment: Path/classpath issue?

Comment: no there is no classpath or path issue.actually the server starts and it closes down suddenly. I dont know why.

Comment: check out log? Do you see any exceptions when it comes up?